# I need to generate .apk file from my ionic project, ionic cordova build is throwing errors

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=permit
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/hussain/project/moodleapp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/hussain/project/moodleapp/platforms/android/build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I uninstalled the cordova and again reinstalled it.

npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the `error messages` that you have posted, in order to generate the `.apk` file for Android, you need to set `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and the `ANDROID_HOME` in your `PATH`. Assuming you are working on `MacOX`, you can add following entries in `.zsh_profile` or `.zshrc` depending on your MacOS version as follows:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/hussain/Library/Android/sdk
```

Similarly, you need to set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`.

Once you have done the same, you can try opening a new terminal session and run the command `ionic cordova build`

Hope that helps.

P.S : Please ensure you have the right version of `Java JDK` installed based on your `Cordova` version.

Comment: its not working I've posted tjhe complete error message above

Answer (score 0):

cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 112 source files in 1289ms
[cordova-plugin-push::before-compile] skipping before_compile hookscript.
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/hussain/project/moodleapp/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 69
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 30.0.3 or higher.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 452ms
Command failed with exit code 1: /home/hussain/project/moodleapp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /home/hussain/project/moodleapp/platforms/android/build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

I am working on ubuntu

Comment: Looks like more suitable for a comment